# Snowy or snowing?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, grammaticality-in-context

There is a sentence from a test:

> It's foggy in Sydney and it's ... in Moscow.

Students are to choose between "snowy" and "snowing". The correct answer is "snowing".
Why can't "snowy" be used here? I think both answers can be right, it depends on the context.
([It's rainy today](https://elt.oup.com/student/americanfamilyandfriends/level03/songs/song_03?cc=us&selLanguage=en))

**Snowy: (of weather or a period of time) characterized by snowfall:**

> a snowy January day

([Source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/snowy))

Comment: No reason I can think of. Although they don't mean quite the same thing, both seem perfectly legitimate to me. This appears to be more of a meteorological than a grammatical question.

Comment: You are right, Julia. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible that snowy would work, but snowing is more similar to foggy.  Both foggy and snowing are weather conditions.  Roughly speaking both foggy and snowing mean the sky is filled with fog or snow respectively.  Snowy, however, is not a weather condition.  Snowy is a more general term than snowing, meaning things are covered with snow.  It can be snowy and snowing or it can be snowy but not snowing.

Answer (score -2):

You are using a verb “it’s”. You are using 3rd person of verb "to be": **is**. That means that sentence is *in present continuous*. The correct answer is "it is snowing" you can also say “it’s a snowy day” because **snowy** is an adverb.

Comment: The word *snowy* modifies the noun "day"; it is, therefore, an *adjective*. The comparative form is used  with adjectives: Today is a very snowy day, but last week it was even ***snowier***.